# Gerar tags com constantes usando XStream em Java

Tags: java, xml

Olá preciso gerar um xml com tags em maiúsculas que teriam que ser necessariamente atributos final na classe modelo para gerar o xml.

Para fazer isso, estou tentando utilizar a API XStream do Java.

Porém sendo estas tags final não consigo gerar, um construtor nem criar seus sets, pois são privadas?

Há alguma maneira de eu resolver com XStream mesmo ou seria melhor outra API Java para resolver o problema?

Aqui o modelo de classe que eu precisaria.
Se eu deixar os atributos sem final, ficariam estranho por necessitar que minhas tags no xml, obrigatoriamente precisem ser maiúsculas?

```
public class Metadados {
  private final String NOME_USUARIO;
  private final String IDADE_USUARIO;
  private final String NUMERO_PROTOCOLO;
}
```

Meu XML precisaria sair assim:

```
<NOME_USUARIO>Paulo</NOME_USUARIO>
<COD_USUARIO>36</COD_USUARIO>
<COD_PROTOCOLO>20170111092247</COD_PROTOCOLO>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção pra não precisar declarar seus atributos em letra maiúscula e com modificar de acesso final, seria a utilização da anotação `@XStreamAlias("nome do atributo")`.

Exemplo:

```
@XStreamAlias("NOME_USUARIO")
private String nomeUsuario;
```

Veja mais na [documentação](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html).

---

Se o atributo precisa ser necessariamente `final`, não faz sentido existir um `setter` pois o modificador de acesso "final" indica que o valor de seu atributo não pode ser alterado após ser inicializado.

```
@XStreamAlias("metadados")
public class Metadados {

    private final String NOME_USUARIO;
    private final String IDADE_USUARIO;
    private final String NUMERO_PROTOCOLO;

    public Metadados(String NOME_USUARIO, String IDADE_USUARIO, String NUMERO_PROTOCOLO) {
        this.NOME_USUARIO = NOME_USUARIO;
        this.IDADE_USUARIO = IDADE_USUARIO;
        this.NUMERO_PROTOCOLO = NUMERO_PROTOCOLO;
    }

    public String getNOME_USUARIO() {
        return NOME_USUARIO;
    }

    public String getIDADE_USUARIO() {
        return IDADE_USUARIO;
    }

    public String getNUMERO_PROTOCOLO() {
        return NUMERO_PROTOCOLO;
    }
}
```

Gerando o xml com XStream:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF8", new NoNameCoder()));
xstream.processAnnotations(Metadados.class);
String xml = xstream.toXML(new Metadados("nome", "20", "123456"));
System.out.println(xml);
```

Resultado:

```
<metadados>
    <NOME_USUARIO>nome</NOME_USUARIO>
    <IDADE_USUARIO>20</IDADE_USUARIO>
    <NUMERO_PROTOCOLO>123456</NUMERO_PROTOCOLO>
</metadados>
```